# Access Map Data generated by Maperative with Leaflet or OpenLayers

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

I am still quite new to mapping, and am trying to implement an offline-solution with either leaflet or OpenLayers (I managed to implement an online example which works). I am trying this using vue.

What I was trying was to generate data with maperative, which then produced a tiles directory, which contains a tiles.json file and directories called 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10, which contain more directories which contain png files with map data.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or show me a little example code how I can display map data from maperative with either vue leaflet or vue openlayers?

I tried modifying some code I found elsewhere like this:

```
<template>
 <l-map
   :center="center"
   :zoom="zoom"
   class="map"
   ref="map"
   @update:zoom="zoomUpdated"
   @update:center="centerUpdated"
 >
   <l-tile-layer
     :url="url"
   >
   </l-tile-layer>
   </l-map>
</template>
<script>
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from 'vue2-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
export default {
 components: {
   LMap,
   LTileLayer
 },
 data () {
   return {
     url: 'file:////home/user/FD/workspace/features/ol-vue-example-master/harvest_assist_ui/src/assets/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png',
     center: [ 50.4193089, 40.6757156 ],
     zoom: 12,
   }
 },
 methods: {
   zoomUpdated (zoom) {
     this.zoom = zoom;
     console.log(this.markers)
   },
   centerUpdated (center) {
     this.center = center;
   }
 }
}
</script>

<style>
 .map {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow :hidden
 }
</style>
for Leaflet, and I tried this for OpenLayers:
<template>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
            <button style="width: 10%; height: 10%" type="button" id="idSubmit" name="Set All" @click="SetAll" class="btn">Apply</button>
  <div ref="map-root"
       style="width: 90%; height: 90%">
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import View from 'ol/View'
  import Map from 'ol/Map'
  import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'
  import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector'
  import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector'
  import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON'

  import 'ol/ol.css'

  export default {
    name: 'MapContainer',
    components: {},
    props: {
      geojson: Object
    },
    data: () => ({
      olMap: null,
      source: null,
      vectorLayer: null,
      selectedFeature: null
    }),
    mounted() {
      this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          features: [],
        }),
      })

      this.source = new OSM();
            var MyLayer = new OSM("mymap","file:///home/user/FD/workspace/features/ol-vue-example-master/src/assets/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 16, alpha: true, isBaseLayer: true, visibility: false});
      this.olMap = new Map({
        target: this.$refs['map-root'],
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: this.source,
          }),
          this.vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new View({
          zoom: 0,
          center: [0, 0],
          constrainResolution: true
        }),
      })
      this.olMap.layers = MyLayer;
      console.debug(MyLayer);       
      this.olMap.on('pointermove', (event) => {
        const hovered = this.olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => feature)
        if (hovered !== this.selectedFeature) {
          this.$set(this, 'selectedFeature', hovered);
        }
      })

      this.updateSource(this.geojson)
    },
    watch: {
      geojson(value) {
        this.updateSource(value)
      },
      selectedFeature(value) {
        this.$emit('select', value)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      SetAll() 
      {
         console.debug("Test");
         console.debug(this.source);
         var osmextent = this.vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent();
         var currentzoom = this.olMap.getView().zoom;
         console.log(this.vectorLayer.getSource());
         //var osmzoom = this.vectorLayer.getSource().getZoom();
         var osmzoom = currentzoom;
         console.debug("BLA");
         console.debug(osmextent);
         console.debug(currentzoom);
         console.debug(osmzoom);
    this.source.getTileGrid().forEachTileCoord(osmextent,parseInt(osmzoom), function(tileCoord)
         {
                      console.debug("BLUBB2");
           var img = document.createElement("img");
           img.onload = function() 
           {
             var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
             canvas.width = this.source.getTileGrid().getTileSize(currentzoom);
             canvas.height = this.source.GetTileGrid().getTileSize(currentzoom);
             var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
             localStorage.setItem('OSM_' + tileCoord[0]+'_'+tileCoord[1]+'_'+(-tileCoord[2]-1), canvas.toDataURL());
             console.debug('OSM_' + tileCoord[0]+'_'+tileCoord[1]+'_'+(-tileCoord[2]-1), canvas.toDataURL());
             img.remove();
             canvas.remove();
             console.debug("BLUBB");
           }
           img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
           img.src = this.source.getTileUrlFunction()(tileCoord);
         });
         
      },
      updateSource(geojson) {
        const view = this.olMap.getView();
        const source = this.vectorLayer.getSource();

        const features = new GeoJSON({
          featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
        }).readFeatures(geojson);

        source.clear();
        source.addFeatures(features);

        view.fit(source.getExtent())
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in the browse debugger console? For security reasons I doubt you can access tile from your local file system.

Comment: Yes, it gave an error about security "Security Error: Content at http://localhost:8080/ may not load or link to file:///home/user/FD/workspace/features/ol-vue-example-master/harvest_assist_ui/src/assets/Tiles/$12/$2513/$1382.png". If I cannot acess a tile from the local file system, how can I access it then ? Over some kind of database I assume ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simplest way would be over local web server. This means you have to put your tiles inside your local web server so they are accessible through it. And I doubt your tile names start with `$` character, so you have to leave it out in your tile access address.

Comment: I'd recommend using relative URLs instead of absolute URLs (no need to have a local webserver that way, IIRC). Do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls if you need a refresher on the subject.

Comment: Yeah, the stuff with the $ was what the code appearently made out of what I typed. In the source-code it was written like that "file:///home/user/FD/workspace/features/ol-vue-example-master/harvest_assist_ui/src/assets/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png". The directory with the Tiles looks like Tiles/tiles.json Tiles/6 Tiles/7 Tiles/8 Tiles/9 Tiles/10. What exactly is the path I need to give to the library ? Thanks in advance! (thanks for the refresher @IvanSanchez also, I will read this)

Comment: Yeah, the stuff with the $ was what the code made out of what I typed. In the source  it was written like "file:///home/user/FD/workspace/features/ol-vue-example-master/harvest_assist_ui/src/assets/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png". The directory with the Tiles looks like Tiles/tiles.json Tiles/6 Tiles/7 Tiles/8 Tiles/9 Tiles/10. What exactly is the path I need to give?The first number with $ seems to be the zoom value from the code. Are those directories 6,7,8,9,10 the supported zoom values or what are they? I am very unsure what this data generated by maperative is and how I need to access it.

Comment: Where `Tiles` directory resides? Is it subdirectory of directory where your map html resides? If not, put it there. Your `url` option will then be `url: 'Tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'`.

Comment: Tiles directory is the directory the Maperative software output. It looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/fLdWqFb. My question is now how do I need to reference this in the code basically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, what are the x y z things. I assume z is the zoom right ? And the  directories 6,7,8,9,10 in the Tiles directory are probably the supported zooms I assume ? I get the error message "may not load or link to file:///assets/Tiles/$10/$627/$345.png".

I tried to load it like this: 

url: 'file://src/assets/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png',
center: [50.4, 40.6],
zoom: 10, any idea what I might do wrong there ? (right now this whole thing is just meant as a prove of concept). Also no idea where it gets the 627 and 345 from.

Comment: What is wrong is described in the above comments. If you don't understand them, ask for clarification. Fact is that you cannot access files from the root of your file system, so you have to put them in a subdirectory under directory were your map page resides.

Comment: Ah, thanks, it was a simple error in the path. But now a different error appears "Security error: May not load or link to file:///Tiles/$10/$625/$346.png. In the source I gave the path as file://assets/Tiles/${z}/${y}/${x}.png. The source code is in src, the Tiles directory is found in src/assets. (so src/assets/Tiles/tiles.json etc.).